# Why would PHPunit ignore .env.testing?

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit

I have a newly installed Laravel 6.4 application running and now trying to get tests working with PHPunit. I want to make configuration changes in `.env.testing` but any changes in here seem to be ignored.

`phpunit.xml` contains this:

```
    <php>
        <server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <server name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
        <server name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="MAIL_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
        <server name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    </php>
```

And I have also have included `$app->loadEnvironmentFrom('/var/www/api/.env.testing');` into `tests/CreatesApplication.php` `createApplication()` method. All paths are correct so I don't understand why it is not reading the file. I've found similar mentions of this issue when googling but none have helped me resolve the issue.

I am running PHPunit with the command `vendor/bin/phpunit`. Does anyone have suggestions on what I can try?

Comment: use `force="true"` and then try. `<server name="APP_ENV" value="testing" force="true"/>`

Comment: Have you cached config? Try `php artisan config:clear`